# Devbridge autocomplete down/up arrow issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery autocomplete by devbridge: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Every time I press the arrow keys to navigate through the suggestions my entire parent div displays none. As soon as I click on the text input again the suggestions reappear. I have not altered the files from github at all, but I don't think this is how it is supposed to function from what I've read scrolling through the $.autocomplete methods. Does anyone have experience with this? Let me know what other information to provide.

I am calling the autocomplete as suggested:

```js
$("#input").autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: "/index.cfm/autocomplete/getLocations"
});
```

My response from the ajax appears to be in the right format:

```html
{"suggestions" : [{"value": "Orlando, OK", "data": 123447},{"value": "Orlando, FL", "data": 101833}]}
```

I can also select certain suggestions when hovering:
[image]

The only functions that don't appear to work correctly are the down and up arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I was calling $.autocomplete within an on keydown. Everything works great now. Sometimes you need to zoom out to fix the problem.